# Not sure if PHP if updating

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

I have a server running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. I remember reading that Ubuntu back-ports patches for PHP, Apache, and MySQL, so the version number of PHP, Apache, and MySQL doesn't change. If that's the case where can I verify it's updating? When I run *apt-get upgrade* or *apt upgrade*, I don't see any patches for PHP, MySQL, or Apache in the output. I disabled automatic upgrades a while ago so I can test these updates before committing them. If I run *php -v,* it shows 7.4.3.

Comment: See this for example http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/p/php7.4/php7.4_7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4/changelog

Comment: For MySQL http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/m/mysql-8.0/mysql-8.0_8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3/changelog

Answer (score 2):

You can run

```
apt changelog <package>
```

to see what security and other updates are installed.

E.g.

```
apt changelog php7.4
```